# MySQL trigger needs tweaking

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger that sets a datetime field in a table row when a new row is inserted. (Don't bother lecturing me that I could do this in the table definition, I have second datetime field that is using that functionality already and you can only do it with one column per table.)

This trigger works great for my purposes:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foobar_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON foobar
        FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.created=NOW();
```

So whenever a new row is inserted, `foobar.created` gets set to the current time. This is great when I do something like:

> INSERT INTO foobar (foo) VALUES ('bar');

The only problem with this is that if I want to explicitly set `foobar.created` in the insert statement, it gets overridden by the trigger.

So,

> INSERT INTO foobar (foo,created) VALUES ('foo','2006-01-01 12:12:12');

results in `foobar.created` equaling the time of the insert, not the time specified in the insert statement.

So my question is: How can I change my trigger to only set `foobar.created` if it doesn't already have a value?

EDIT:

In response to james_bond below, here is what worked:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS foobar_insert$$
CREATE TRIGGER foobar_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON foobar
    FOR EACH ROW
      IF NEW.created IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.created=NOW();
      END IF$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note I had to include `DELIMITER` statements because the `IF` statement required an interior semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for `NEW.created` is `NULL`, if is set it's because you have set it in your insert statement,if it is NULL then it needs the current time as value, something like this will do the trick:

```
if NEW.created is NULL THEN
   SET NEW.created = now();
end if
```